# About the migration from C2DM to GCM and the google account

Tags: android, notifications

I have a question about the migration from C2DM to GCM in my app.

Right now, I'm using C2DM, and the people using my apps are required to have a google account created in the Account & Sync menu.
If I migrate to GCM, will this still be required ?
Will it work with custom ROM under Android 4.0.3 ?

Thanks, have a good weekend.

Comment: I have used GCM on a phone with Cyanogenmod 7 with Google Apps installed and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

From [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html):

GCM uses an existing connection for Google services. For pre-3.0 devices, this requires users to set up their Google account on their mobile devices. A Google account is not a requirement on devices running Android 4.0.4 or higher.

There is no reason why it shouldn't work on a custom rom (if the Google Apps are installed), so yes it would work.

Comment: If I'm running Android 4.0.4 but still using C2DM, do I need a Google account on the device to receive pushes?

Comment: @Matthew Yes, you need a Google account afaik.